# freshclam error, "clamd.conf" file not found

Tags: updates, configuration, clamav

When I run the following command:

```
sudo freshclam
```

If there are found to be updates to the virus definitions etc then at the end of the output comes this error message

```
ERROR: NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```

But if I run the command when there are no new updates available, then I don't receive this error message. Why am I getting this error message (as I have not got it before when running the same operations)? And can I fix the problem (if it needs fixing)?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and ClamAV (the latest version).

---

**Information update:**

This command:

```
ls -al /var/log/clamav/
```

Outputs:

```
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  2 clamav clamav  4096 Feb 22 11:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 root   syslog  4096 Feb 24 18:26 ..
-rw-r-----  1 clamav adm    46790 Feb 24 18:31 freshclam.log
-rw-r-----  1 clamav adm    59109 Feb 22 11:14 freshclam.log.1
```

And this command:

```
more /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```

Outputs:

```
/etc/clamav/clamd.conf: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried reinstalling `clamav`, but I still get the same error when running `sudo freshclam`.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Ok, I have added that information to the question, I have also corrected some other information.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It seems that installing clamav via `apt-get install clamav` doesn't actually install the clamav daemon; it only installs the freshclam daemon.  You'll probably want to install `clamav-daemon` as well.  The first time clamd runs, it'll create `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf`.

Note that the clamav package does install `clamscan`, which you can invoke manually to scan specific files/directories.  However, by default, nothing will be scanned automatically. clamav-daemon allows scans to be triggered remotely, but even that doesn't schedule scans or provide realtime protection.

This is a good reminder that you should never just install security software and forget about it.  You need to make sure it's working properly.  I'm sure plenty of people run `sudo apt-get install clamav`, then just assume it's working in the background--when, in reality, all that's running is freshclam.

If you're actually looking for realtime protection, instead of just trying to run a scan, [user61995 mentioned a potential solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/720113/168722).  I haven't tested it.

**tl;dr:** `sudo apt install clamav-daemon` to fix the error, but you still have to run scans manually to be protected; these packages don't provide realtime protection.

Comment: So as it now runs in the background, is this going to be like real-time protection, or just scheduled scans?

Comment: According to `man clamd`: "The  daemon  listens  for  incoming connections on Unix and/or TCP socket and scans files or directories on demand. It reads the configuration from /etc/clamav/clamd.conf"  It looks like you have to write something on your end that connects to each of your servers regularly and triggers scans.  I guess if you want to automatically scan a single machine at a set interval, the easiest way is to add a cronjob.  Looks like there isn't any realtime protection.

Comment: +1 I found this answer to work - and to actually install `clamav-daemon` as this answer suggests, use: `apt-get install clamav-daemon` or `sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon` (if non-root user with sudo-er privileges) I did this after running `sudo apt-get install clamav`

Comment: As of 2023 this is still true for 20.04 LTS ubuntu. also despite having the documentaion https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV not explicitly specifying we need to install the daemon ans it is only in the «Run as Daemon» and stating it is  2 differents option `For manual use: install the package clamav. For automated use: install the package clamav-daemon. ` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

Answer (score 2):

On-access scanning exists if you are looking for that. Take a look at the docs: [On Access Scanning](https://docs.clamav.net/manual/OnAccess.html).

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: OnAccess scanning documentation link: https://docs.clamav.net/manual/OnAccess.html