# Clamtk virus scan stopped working on Ubuntu16.04.3 and shows no files scanned?

Tags: clamav

Clamtk used to work but suddenly for no reason it stopped working on Ubuntu16.04.3. When I click a folder to scan it just shows "0 files scanned" and zero threats even though I have many files in the folder. It used to work last couple week and it shows there are 23705 antivirus signatures installed already. I have been able to run freshclam by killing freshclam and then running it but still clamtk fails to scan any files.

Comment: "Clamtk used to work" No it didn't :-P (well it might have some something cpu intensive but not catch virusses :D ) See `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` If anything is wrong it should be shown there (post the errors if you see one).

Comment: I get this error: "
Fri Aug 25 21:37:14 2017 -> Database updated (6308882 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 27.96.54.66)
Fri Aug 25 21:37:14 2017 -> ERROR: NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf"

Comment: Good. Check that file on typing errors or add it to the question and we will find the problem. Did you perhaps edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using info from [freshclam error, "clamd.conf" file not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589318/freshclam-error-clamd-conf-file-not-found/720113#720113)

```
sudo apt install clamav-daemon
```

and then to complete the fix in ClamTK **Settings > Update Assistant** I had to set it to *My computer automatically receives updates* and then ClamTK began scanning files again normally.