# ClamAV: clamd.ctl file is not getting created on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, configuration, clamav

I have ubuntu 16.04.6 version and I'm trying to install & run the `clamdscan` on it to check for antiviruses.

I've used the [installation instructions as given in their website](https://www.clamav.net/download.html#otherversions). ie.

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

The above 2 commands works fine. But when I try to download the definitions (which I'm assuming is mandatory after the above) by running the command

```
sudo freshclam
```

it fails throwing the following error:

```
^Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl: No such file or directory
```

According to [this accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589318/freshclam-error-clamd-conf-file-not-found/632911), the file should get created after installing `clamav-daemon` but obviously that does not happen.

Answer (score 17):

I faced this issue on my **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** machine,

What I did was:

1. run `sudo systemctl stop clamav-daemon.service`
2. then run `sudo rm /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` (sometimes it gets locked)
3. start the service `sudo systemctl start clamav-daemon.service`

to ensure everything is OK run `sudo systemctl status clamav-daemon.service` and the output should look something like this:

```
➜  ~ sudo systemctl status clamav-daemon.service
● clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d
             └─extend.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-05-03 05:03:51 EEST; 4s ago
       Docs: man:clamd(8)
             man:clamd.conf(5)
             https://www.clamav.net/documents/
    Process: 6122 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/clamav (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 6124 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown clamav /run/clamav (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 6138 (clamd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 14203)
     Memory: 367.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-daemon.service
             └─6138 /usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=true

May 03 05:03:51 user systemd[1]: Starting Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon...
May 03 05:03:51 user systemd[1]: Started Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon.
```

> Now run `sudo freshclam` and check the log file (or console output)

```
Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020 -> --------------------------------------
Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020
Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020 -> daily.cvd database is up to date (version: 25800, sigs: 2331970, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020 -> main.cvd database is up to date (version: 59, sigs: 4564902, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Sun May  3 05:04:02 2020 -> bytecode.cvd database is up to date (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

I found that after you run the:

```
freshclam
```

And get this error:

```
Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl: No such file or directory
```

You just need to run restart for the demon:

```
service clamav-daemon restart
```

And then `freshclam`  again and all works.

Answer (score 2):

Add a sock file for ClamAV:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/clamav/clamd.sock
sudo chown clamav:clamav /var/lib/clamav/clamd.sock
```

Then, edit `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` - uncomment this line:

```
LocalSocket /var/lib/clamav/clamd.sock
```

Save the file and restart `clamav-daemon.service`

Another error:

```
sudo freshclam

Downloading daily-25578.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-25579.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-25580.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-25581.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-25582.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-25583.cdiff [100%]
daily.cld updated (version: 25583, sigs: 1778105, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Downloading bytecode-331.cdiff [100%]
bytecode.cld updated (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
Database updated (6344448 signatures) from database.clamav.net (IP: 104.16.219.84)
WARNING: Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /run/clamav/clamd.ctl: No such file or directory
```

[image: clam]

Add a sock file for ClamAV:

```
sudo touch /run/clamav/clamd.sock
sudo chown clamav:clamav /run/clamav/clamd.sock

sudo systemctl restart clamav-daemon.service
sudo freshclam

ClamAV update process started at Thu Sep 26 11:47:12 2019
main.cvd is up to date (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
daily.cld is up to date (version: 25583, sigs: 1778105, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
```

That's it.

Comment: Is there no better way to do this while running provision script on a server ? I mean, locally it could work. But i'm trying to run provision scripts to execute commands on AWS EC2 instance and opening and uncommenting a file on the fly in the server seems weird.

Comment: just type `nano /etc/clamav/clamd.conf` uncomment and save. This tutorial fixed an issue on my system.

Comment: if you still get another error `/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl` no such file or directory create and give ownership to a sock file in that directory as well as specified in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To reconfigure clamav run

```
dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon
```

Please read `/usr/share/doc/clamav-daemon/README.Debian.gz` for details

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this issue, it's likely that the clam daemon just hasn't fully started yet. You can run "clamd" to start the daemon synchronously and you should be able to scan files after it fully starts.