# Clamav-daemon on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS: Why is clamd socket file not created in /var/run/clamav?

Tags: 16.04, clamav, sockets

On Ubuntu 18.04 server a socket file is created when starting clamav-daemon without problem. On an older server using the 16.04.6 LTS the socket file is just not created whatever I tried. Even I create it first according to the answer posted here [ClamAV: clamd.ctl file is not getting created on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170774/clamav-clamd-ctl-file-is-not-getting-created-on-ubuntu), it will disappear, when clamd starts. I also did a purge of all clamav packages and reinstalled them, same behaviour.

I figured out the clamd-version is one day and one build older in Ubuntu 16.04.6 than clamav.

16.04.6 LTS:

```
$ clamd --version
ClamAV 0.101.4/25612/Thu Oct 24 10:59:15 2019
$ clamscan --version
ClamAV 0.101.4/25613/Fri Oct 25 11:00:25 2019
```

whereas it is the same on 18.04.3 LTS:

```
$ clamd --version
ClamAV 0.101.4/25613/Fri Oct 25 11:00:25 2019
$ clamscan --version
ClamAV 0.101.4/25613/Fri Oct 25 11:00:25 2019
```

Will the build one day later fix this problem? I tried to install the clamav-daemon for Ubuntu 18.04 on the 16.04 but it failed due to dependencies.

The configuration seems OK

```
$ cat /etc/clamav/clamd.conf | grep Socket
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
FixStaleSocket true
LocalSocketGroup clamav
LocalSocketMode 666
```

but no socket file for clamd is created.

```
$ ls -l /var/run/clamav/
total 4
srw-rw-rw- 1 clamav clamav 0 Okt 26 08:12 clamav-milter.ctl
-rw-r--r-- 1 clamav clamav 4 Okt 26 08:12 clamav-milter.pid
```

Thus, as a consequence, amavisd-new is unable to connect to clamd via the socket.
How to get the socket for clamd on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem today by reconfiguring clamav-daemon:

```
dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon
```

Even without changing any values that seemed to kick something and get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Clamav daemon may take really long time to start, or better to load signatures. On one of my systems, it is taking more than 6 minutes.

And, socket is unfortunately created only after everything is loaded.

Try to check log files if there is message similar to

```
Loaded 8794448 signatures.
```

And after that, there should be about twenty more lines. That is the moment when socket should appear.