# Ubuntu server 18.04: clamAV does not work due to missing /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl

Tags: server, clamav

I have a problem with ubuntu server 18.04. I have clamAV installed that connects via unix socket domain `/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl`. ClamAV works well for a while, then the file clamd.ctl disappears from the previous path and I need to manually create it or to restart the system.
I already tried with sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon.

This is my file `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf`

```
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
FixStaleSocket true
# TemporaryDirectory is not set to its default /tmp here to make overriding
# the default with environment variables TMPDIR/TMP/TEMP possible
User root
ScanMail true
ScanArchive true
ArchiveBlockEncrypted false
MaxDirectoryRecursion 15
FollowDirectorySymlinks false
FollowFileSymlinks false
ReadTimeout 180
MaxThreads 12
MaxConnectionQueueLength 15
StreamMaxLength 10M
LogFileMaxSize 0
LogSyslog false
LogFacility LOG_LOCAL6
```

This is a script run with crontab

```
#!/bin/bash

# update
#freshclam

FILETODOWNLOAD="main.cvd daily.cvd bytecode.cvd";

for F in ${FILETODOWNLOAD}; do
 sudo rm -f /var/lib/clamav/$F
 wget http://database.clamav.net/$F -P /var/lib/clamav
 sudo chown clamav:clamav /var/lib/clamav/$F
 sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/clamav/$F
done

# scan
LOGFILE="/var/log/clamav/clamav-$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').log";
#EMAIL_MSG="Please see the log file attached.";
#EMAIL_FROM="clamav-daily@domain";
#EMAIL_TO="webmaster@domain";
DIRTOSCAN="/var/www /home/master/";

for D in ${DIRTOSCAN}; do
 DIRSIZE=$(du -sh "$D" 2>/dev/null | cut -f1);

 echo "Starting a daily scan of "$D" directory.
 Amount of data to be scanned is "$DIRSIZE".";

 clamscan -ri "$D" >> "$LOGFILE";

 # get the value of "Infected lines"
 MALWARE=$(tail "$LOGFILE"|grep Infected|cut -d" " -f3);
done
```

Any idea?

P.S. I already tried with this solution: [ClamAV: clamd.ctl file is not getting created on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170774/clamav-clamd-ctl-file-is-not-getting-created-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Xubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop. And I also tried the other solution with no success.
What worked for me was to purge clamav.

```
sudo apt-get purge clamav
```

Maybe you have to purge the daemon too. Don't remember.
Make sure that `/etc/clamav/` and `/var/run/clamav` are not existing anymore.

Then reinstall clamav and the daemon in one command. (I got the feeling, that if you install clamav and then the daemon the first might already be running and blocking some files. But that's just a guess.)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clamav clamav-daemon
```

After that, it worked fine for me.

After the install command the file /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl should be created.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But it does not work for me.

Comment: This was the solution for me, didn't expect it!